# Question: $X \hookrightarrow Y$ implies $ Z \cap X \hookrightarrow Z \cap Y$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $X,Y,Z$ be some Banach spaces and assume that $X \hookrightarrow
>  Y$, i.e $X$ is embedded continuously into $Y$. Can we claim then that
>   $ Z \cap X \hookrightarrow Z \cap Y$?

By a set theory approach, this seems correct but I'm not sure about the injections here. Maybe my question is quite elementary but since I haven't taken many courses in functional analysis, I would really appreciate if somebody could confirm or reject this via a counterexample.

**EDIT:** My question is motivated by the following spaces:

$X \equiv W^{1,2}(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$, $Y \equiv W^{1,2}(0,T;W^{-1,2}(\Omega))$ and $Z \equiv L^2(0;T;W^{1,2}(\Omega))$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $Z$? An embedding is injective, but if $X\subset Z$ and $Z\cap Y=\emptyset$ then your claim would be incorrect.

Comment: @FlorisClaassens You 're right. I just edited

Comment: Is what you mean the following? If $f:X\hookrightarrow Y$ and $Z\subseteq X$ then $Z\equiv fZ$? Is so, the answer is yes.